# How do I build 2 docker images from maven, in separate phases?

Tags: maven, docker, docker-maven-plugin

I use [`io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.28.0`](https://dmp.fabric8.io/) in a Maven project and I need to build 2 different Docker images, in different phases:

1. One for the `integration-test` phase, to run some database for the integration tests. I would build it with some resources from the project (SQL files defining the schema).
2. One at the end, after the tests have passed (maybe during `package`), with the complete application.

My problem is that only the first image is built.

I tried to reference the image aliases in the `<configuration>` of the `<execution>` elements, but it doesn't seem to work. Only the first image is considered:

```
$ mvn install

...
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.28.0:build (start) @ dmp-example ---
[INFO] Building tar: /home/cosmin/workspaces/photon/test/dmp-example/target/docker/example/db-test/latest/tmp/docker-build.tar
[INFO] DOCKER> [example/db-test:latest] "example-db-test": Created docker-build.tar in 28 milliseconds
[INFO] DOCKER> [example/db-test:latest] "example-db-test": Built image sha256:d8233
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.28.0:start (start) @ dmp-example ---
[INFO] DOCKER> [example/db-test:latest] "example-db-test": Start container 47883d799641
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.28.0:stop (stop) @ dmp-example ---
[INFO] DOCKER> [example/db-test:latest] "example-db-test": Stop and removed container 47883d799641 after 0 ms
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ dmp-example ---
[INFO] Installing /home/cosmin/workspaces/photon/test/dmp-example/target/dmp-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/cosmin/.m2/repository/com/example/dmp-example/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/dmp-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/cosmin/workspaces/photon/test/dmp-example/pom.xml to /home/cosmin/.m2/repository/com/example/dmp-example/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/dmp-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.28.0:build (build) @ dmp-example ---
[INFO] Building tar: /home/cosmin/workspaces/photon/test/dmp-example/target/docker/example/db-test/latest/tmp/docker-build.tar
[INFO] DOCKER> [example/db-test:latest] "example-packaged": Created docker-build.tar in 6 milliseconds
[INFO] DOCKER> [example/db-test:latest] "example-packaged": Built image sha256:d8233
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

The second image is not created, and the ID of the first one is also used when the second one should be built:

```
$ docker images "example/*"
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
example/db-test     latest              d8233ab899d4        7 days ago          1.2MB
```

Would there be another way of doing it?

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dmp-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.28.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <alias>example-db-test</alias>
                            <name>example/db-test:latest</name>
                            <build>
                                <from>busybox</from>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                        <image>
                            <alias>example-packaged</alias>
                            <name>example/packaged:latest</name>
                            <build>
                                <from>alpine</from>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <images>
                                <image>
                                    <alias>example-db-test</alias>
                                </image>
                            </images>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <images>
                                <image>
                                    <alias>example-db-test</alias>
                                </image>
                            </images>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <images>
                                <image>
                                    <alias>example-packaged</alias>
                                </image>
                            </images>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

For keeping the example simple, I used `busybox` and `alpine` as the base images, but that has no relevance.

Comment: The last execution of the docker-maven-plugin is missing the phase; is that just a typo? If not, could be the issue.

Comment: I just added the `package` phase (and updated the question), but it doesn't make any difference. I think the `package` phase is the default. Also, you can see in the console output that `example-packaged` is mentioned, but with the same ID/hash (`d8233`) as `example-db-test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving the full configuration for the image you want into the execution, instead of using global plugin config.

```
<execution>
    <id>build</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <configuration>
        <images>
            <image>
                <alias>example-packaged</alias>
                <name>example/packaged:latest</name>
                <build>
                    <from>alpine</from>
                </build>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>build</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```